# Will reinstalling OS from recovery mode preserve iTunes library?

Tags: macos, recovery

I have a Macbook Pro with a broken OS (computer was turned off during an  update and won’t boot any more).

The Macbook contains some user data that hasn’t been backed up in a while, including a valuable iTunes library.

Will those data be preserved when reinstalling OS X (Yosemite) from recovery mode, or is there an easy way to get hold of it again?

Answer (score 1):

Reinstalling OS X or macOS from Recovery mode or an Installer will not delete any files.

Comment: Any *user* files, right? Not even those /User/Shared? See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/405833/is-users-shared-preserved-after-reinstalling-the-os

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it should. The last time I restored an OS (El Capitan) the user data was preserved, but I would definitely recommend booting from recovery then trying to back up before restoring. Once you make the changes, if something breaks then it's too late unless you have a backup. Consider Carbon Copy Cloner or SuperDuper! to facilitate.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you don't explicitly erase then you should be okay. You can also use target disk mode or something else to try and make a quick backup before moving forward.