# Is /Users/Shared preserved after reinstalling the OS?

Tags: macos, install

Reinstalling* the OS preserves the contents of user homes in `/Users` but is `/Users/Shared` also preserved untouched?

Is my data stored in `/Users/Shared` safe? (I do have backups.)

* via Recovery or standalone installer on top of an existing installation without erasing the disk or partition. Does it make a difference whether it's via Recovery or standalone installer?

Comment: What steps do you take when you reinstall?

Comment: @bmike, see my edited answer. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are updating the OS to a newer version, either a point upgrade or 'major version' (e.g. from Catalina to Big Sur), then yes, files in `/Users/Shared` are left untouched.

I have lots of files in `/Users/Shared` and have never had them wiped by an OS upgrade.

I haven't use Recovery on a working system, but suspect the results would be the same. An OS installer does not wipe the disk by itself.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, when you install OS from TimeMachine or Startup Disk, OSinstaller ask you what info you want to install, this include

- Apps
- Users
- Settings and
- **Other Data**

And calculates size of each section, giving you the option of checkmark each one individually.
The Users/Shared data are included in **Other Data**, so if you check this, you will preserve Shared data, if not, you don't.

Hope is clear, english is not my native language

Comment: I think you're describing what the Migration Assistant can transfer from another Mac or a Time Machine backup. This is different from what's (automatically) preserved during a reinstallation.

Comment: Yes, I’m describing Migration Assistant, I’ve done myself a couple of times recently.  
When reinstalling, I think is just OS what is installed and later give you the option to migrate, although I haven’t done myself this way, and I cannot confirm.